# Getting org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException

Tags: java, file, xlsm

I tried the following code to read the contents of `.xlsm` file

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class ReadMacroExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\samplewkbk.xlsm");

            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
            System.out.println(workbook);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following expection:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:87)
    at wipro.ReadMacroExcel.main(ReadMacroExcel.java:13)
```

I use the following jar files:

```
poi-ooxml-3.11.jar
poi-3.9.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-beta1.jar
dom4j-1.6.jar
```

Comment: Why are you using different versions for all your POI libraries?

Comment: Oh! so that is the problem? Will use the same version and check. Thanks

Comment: Don't know if that is the problem, but using the same version throughout will at least eliminate a possible cause. 3.12 seems to be the most recent.

Comment: I think using 3.9 version for all the poi jars will be more appropriate

Comment: using similar version eliminates this exception, Thank you everyone